# Symfony2 console doesn't interact

Tags: php, linux, symfony, bundle

When I was creating projects in Symfony2 on Windows there were no problems, but now (linux) I got something like this: 
when I want to generate bundle without any parameters I get

```
 [RuntimeException]                        
  The "namespace" option must be provided.
```

When I type in the namespace I get:

```
  [RuntimeException]                  
  The "dir" option must be provided.
```

I can create bundle only if I give all the necessary arguments at the beginning and I'm kinda lazy person and it's quite annoying for me that console doesn't ask about namespace or anything. Is there any chance to repair this?:P

EDIT: actually this happens whenever I try to run function which requires arguments.

Comment: Which version of symfony it is ? Do you run the check.php script to check your environment ?

Comment: It was the newest Standard 2.3.1 but also one from the previouses versions, i don't remember which one. Check.php showed me info about php accelerator, about short_open_tag and date.timezone only. Everything else is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried too to create a bundle with Netbeans or Eclipse but i have encountered the same problem.
The unique solution is to create your bundle with the Terminal.
All the process will run normally, and you'll only to answer the questions for finish your creation.
I'll come back to you if i've other solutions.
Cordially.

Answer (score 2):

your problem doesn't come from netbeans, I use phpstorm and I had the same problem.

later I found out that the problem comes from symfony to solve it go to your project folder for me it was like: 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/MyProject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/console and open file Application.php in a text editor
search for

```
$input->setInteractive(false);
```

then comment it like this : 
`//$input->setInteractive(false);`

it should perfectly work now  !